# How can I Position a PrimeNG DIalog Box Over the Clicked Element--Rather than Static on the Page?

Tags: angular, dialog, primeng

I have a fullcalendar component (version 6.1.1) in my Angular app (version 13.2.0). My app is styled with primeNG, and I am attempting to use PrimeNG's built-in dialog functionality to add a dialog box for each event on-click in my fullcalendar component. The first part is done--the dialog box renders on click and it shows the information I desire. Now, though, I want to be able to position it above the clicked element (in this case, fullcalendar event) rather than statically in the center of the page, top of the page, whatever.

I have tried setting the position property of the p-dialog box to a variable equal to the clicked element's x and y coordinates. That did not impact the positioning, and PrimeNG documentation seems to indicate that the position property only accepts the following options now: "center", "top", "bottom", "left", "right", "top-left", "top-right", "bottom-left" or "bottom-right".

I have tried manipulating the CSS of the generated dialog box, but I'm really struggling with identifying the correct selectors to manipulate to achieve my goals. For instance, I know the following options don't work (and plenty of others I attempted):

```
      :host ::ng-deep .p-dialog-right {
        top: 0 !important;
        right: auto !important;
        bottom: auto !important;
        left: 0 !important;
      }
```

```
      :host ::ng-deep .p-dialog-mask.p-dialog-right {
        top: 0 !important;
        right: auto !important;
        bottom: auto !important;
        left: 0 !important;
      }
```

```
      :host ::ng-deep .p-dialog .p-dialog-right {
        top: 0 !important;
        right: auto !important;
        bottom: auto !important;
        left: 0 !important;
      }
```

Currently, this is the JS function that opens the dialog box (as set in the calendarOptions object's eventClick property). I added everything from "const rect ..." down to attempt to get an x,y coordinate pair for the top left position of the clicked event. It does work (the console returns an x and y value) but I can't figure out how to apply it to the positioning of the my p-dialog box.

```
  public openDialog(event: any): void {
    this.visibility = true;
    const clickedEvent: EventInput = {
      title: event.event.title,
      start: event.event.start !== null ? event.event.start : undefined,
      end: event.event.end !== null ? event.event.end : undefined,
      location: event.event.extendedProps['location'],
      organizer: event.event.extendedProps['organizer'],
      faculty: event.event.extendedProps['faculty'],
      backgroundColor: event.event.backgroundColor
    };
    this.clickedEvent = clickedEvent;
    const eventClickArg: EventClickArg = {
      el: event.el,
      event: event.event,
      jsEvent: event.jsEvent,
      view: event.view
    };
    const rect = event.el.getBoundingClientRect();
    const x = rect.left + window.pageXOffset;
    const y = rect.top + window.pageYOffset;

    console.log('dialogPosition before:', this.dialogPosition);
    this.dialogPosition = `${x},${y}-50`;
    console.log('dialogPosition after:', this.dialogPosition)
  }
```

And, although it isn't working, here is the line from my HTML that attempts to set the position for the p-dialog:

```
<p-dialog header={{clickedEvent?.title}} [closable]="true" [(visible)]="visibility" position="{{dialogPosition}}">
```

Has anyone succeeded in modifying the location of their dialog box using PrimeNG? Or have any suggestions for how to proceed?

As you can see, I have tried to insert "x,y" coordinates into the position property of p-dialog and modify positioning through CSS. The former does not seem to work at all (perhaps its been deprecated) and the latter I am stumped on the selectors to use in my css file.